# How to programmatically read the path of a rest service?

Tags: java, rest, path, restful-url, request-mapping

suppose I have the following simple rest defined:

```
@RequestMapping("/user/data")
@ResponseBody
public String getUserDetails(@RequestParam int id) {
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to read the path string problematically by another part of the code (i.e. from a different method altogether) ?
Something like:

```
String restPath = SomeReflection.getPath("getuserdetails"); // received value: "/user/data"
```

WDYT?
thanks!

**Solved!**
 here's the implementation I needed:

```
public String getUrlFromRestMethod(Class controllerClass, String methodName) {

        try {
            Method method = controllerClass.getMethod(methodName);
            if (method != null && method.isAnnotationPresent(RequestMapping.class)) {

                RequestMapping requestMappingAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
                return requestMappingAnnotation.toString();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();//TODO
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you wanna access that value programmatically even from another class, then maybe you can start working out your solution from this example:

```
    //get all methods defined in ClassA
    Method[] methods = ClassA.class.getMethods();
    for (Method m : methods) {
        //pick only the ones annotated with "@RequestMapping"
        if (m.isAnnotationPresent(RequestMapping.class)) {
            RequestMapping ta = m.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
            System.out.println(ta.value()[0].toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add a HttpServletRequest request in your method, and then from there go request.getServletPath()

ei

```
public String getUserDetails(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam int id) {
```

Or if this is done in Spring http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{day}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String, Appointment> getForDay(@PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) Date day, Model model) {
    return appointmentBook.getAppointmentsForDay(day);
}
```

Comment: I should have specified - I'm looking on reaching the path from an external class\method

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/owners/{ownerId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)  
public String findOwner(@PathVariable String ownerId, Model model) {  
  Owner owner = ownerService.findOwner(ownerId);    
  model.addAttribute("owner", owner);    
  return "displayOwner";   
}
```

maybe u can call its value.